# What’s the difference between jogar and brincar?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, verbos, diferenças

Can I use *jogar* instead of *brincar* in the following passage?

> Eu vim conversar com ela sobre o que fazer com as crianças. Ela disse que poderíamos ir ao parque e deixá-los **brincar**. Depois de ter falado com ela, fomos lá e não havia muitos meninos **brincando**. No caminho para casa, fomos até o Mcdonalds para comprar Happy Meals porque um deles disse que ficou com fome. Depois então nós fomos para casa.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to change your text so that it sounds more idiomatic.  You can always change it back to what it was if you don't like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In European Portuguese

- Jogar > Play as in play a game, a sport or a match
- Brincar > Play as in  child's play, to toy with, or play with a toy

In that case they don't seem interchangeable so I would say no, you can't use "Jogar" instead of "Brincar" although Brazilian Portuguese may use it slightly differently.

Comment: jogar involves players, brincar does not.

Answer (score 6):

In pt-BR "brincar" and "jogar" **are not interchangeable** though you could easily be performing both actions at the same time.

- **"jogar" is usually a transitive verb** - jogamos futebol, volleyball, basketball, rugby, chess, checkers, cards, monopoly, ping-pong, no bicho (an illegal Brazilian lottery), nos cavalos (também apostamos nos cavalos), table-football, etc.
- **"brincar" can be an intransitive verb** - "as crianças estão brincando no parque", "eu estava brincando quando disse aquilo" (I wasn't serious).  but **it can also be an indirect transitive verb**, where "você brinca **de** alguma coisa" - "as crianças estavam brincando de esconde-esconde".
- And you can perform both actions at the same time: "as crianças estão brincando lá fora. Elas estão jogando peteca" (Se é que alguém ainda joga peteca nos dias de hoje.)

As for your question, you couldn't use "jogar" instead or "brincar" in your text, unless you had previously mentioned a game the children would play or a game you would see the kids playing at the park.

"O baseball havia se tornado uma coqueluche. Fomos ao parque e havia muitos meninos jogando."

Comment: Se for comum as crianças jogarem bola. A mãe pergunta "onde estão as crianças?", e o pai responde "estão jogando lá fora.". No geral deve-se dizer o que se joga quando se usa o verbo jogar, mas não é obrigatório se houver contexto ou entendimento prévio da situação.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Concordo, não é obrigatório. Pode-se dizer qualquer coisa: "estão brincando de bola", "estão jogando no quintal", "estão jogando com a bola", etc.  Mas como nossas perguntas e respostas são mais dirigidas a quem está aprendendo o portuguès, é sempre bom esquecer as variedades pouco usadas e ensinar o que é idiomático.  Por esse motivo é que insisto em que geralmente "quem joga, joga alguma coisa".

Comment: @AndréLyra Também, conforme já mencionei, é idiomático  usar "jogar" como verbo intransitivo quando o jogo em questão já é de conhecimento do interlocutor.  ex:  "Já não jogo atualmente".   "Jogar foi a minha ruína".   "Messie e Ronaldo jogam muito".

Comment: Também concordo que a distinção fundamental neste caso é que *jogar* exige que haja um jogo específico que teria de estar no mínimo implícito (e.g., *pegaram na bola e foram jogar*). Mais lateralmente, há uns tantos jogos/brincadeiras com os quais, pelo menos em Portugal, tanto podemos usar *jogar* como *brincar*: *brincar/jogar às escondidas, aos polícias e ladrões*.

Comment: @Jacinto  Em pt-BR dizemos "brincar de esconde-esconde" e "brincar de polícia e ladrão", mas não "jogar........"

Comment: desta forma, brincar de amarelinha (pular amarelinha) é um jogo como os citados pelo @Jacinto e são brincados.

Answer (score 4):

Os dois verbos são muito ricos em sentidos, mas acredito que brincar seja mais amplo do que jogar. Jogar pode ser uma forma de brincar. Exemplo: as crianças estão brincando no vídeo-game; quando eu era criança brincava muito de futebol. Esses jogos são brincadeiras também.

Posso, entretanto, brincar de carrinho ou de boneca - no caso das meninas. São brincadeiras e não jogos. Quando falamos brincar lembramos das crianças, pois elas brincam o tempo todo.

Brincar também é empregado como sarcasmo ou zueira. Exemplo: "eu não estava brincando com você cara, não é nada disso"; "você está de brincadeira!"; "para de ficar me zuando, meu!".

Também quando estamos nos distraindo com algo é uma forma de brincadeira. Exemplo: "gosto de brincar com o meu cachorro quando chego em casa"; "você não para de brincar com o chaveiro"; "quando eu era criança brincava de carrinho de rolimã".

O dicionário Aulete (http://www.aulete.com.br/brincar) traz as seguintes definições para o verbo **brincar**:

> **(brin.car)**
>
>   v.
>   1. Entreter-se com um objeto ou uma atividade qualquer [int. : As crianças brincam o dia todo.] [tr. + com : Ela brinca com as bonecas da irmã.]
>   2. Distrair-se com jogos de criança, representanto ou simulando alguma coisa ou ação. [tr. + de : Brinca r de polícia e ladrão]
>   3. Agitar ou manipular por entretenimento. [tr. + com : Enquanto esperava, brincava com o chaveiro, distraído.]
>   **4. Não levar em consideração; ZOMBAR [tr. + com : Não brinque com coisas sérias!]
>
>   5. Gracejar [tr. + com : Evita brincar com o colega, pois sabe que ele fica sem graça.] [int. : Não me leve a sério, eu estava brincando.: "Por que acreditariam em mim, brincou."(FolhaSP, 22.01.99)" ( ]**
>
>   6. Agitar-se com movimentos graciosos [int. : Os galhos das árvores brincavam ao vento.]
>   7. Tomar parte em (folguedos carnavalescos) [td. : brincar o carnaval.] [int. : Vestida de colombina, ela brincou a noite inteira.]
>   8. Aproveitar, desfrutar [td. : Brinquei minha infância no interior de Minas]
>   9. Bras. Ter relação libidinosa com [tr. + com : Gostava de brincar com sua garota no sofá]
>   10. Fig. Oscilar, tremer [int. : Uma gota de chuva brincava na ponta da folha]
>   11. Fig. Exibir-se, mostrar-se [int. : Um sorriso contido brinca nos lábios da Monalisa]
>   12. Tratar, levar de maneira imprudente, leviana [ti. + com : Quem brinca com a vida acaba se dando mal]
>   13. Manipular (algo) sem o devido cuidado [tr. + com : Não brinque com fogo, pode ser perigoso.]

Para o verbo **jogar** o mesmo dicionário (http://www.aulete.com.br/jogar) traz as seguintes definições:

> **(jo.gar)**
>
>   v.
>   1. Participar de jogo ou partida (de); praticar (jogo ou esporte), profissionalmente ou como entretenimento. [td. : jogar tênis/ gamão/ batalha naval.] [int. : Brasil e Argentina jogam esta noite: Leia as instruções para saber como jogar.] [tr. + contra : O Brasil jogou contra o Peru.] [ta. : O zagueiro jogou mal ontem.]
>   2. Participar de (jogos de azar), ger. apresentando um comportamento viciado. [td. : Não passa uma noite sem jogar pôquer.] [int. : Fica o dia inteiro nesse bar bebendo e jogando: Não conseguia parar de jogar.]
>   3. Fazer apostas ou ter o vício de apostar (em jogos de azar). [tr. + em : Jogava na roleta e nos cavalos.]
>   4. Fig. Aventurar, arriscar temerariamente, expor à sorte (dinheiro, bens etc.). [tdr. + em : Jogou todas as suas economias no mercado de ações: Jogou seu bom nome num negócio moralmente discutível: Decidiu jogar suas fichas no 25.]
>   5. Atirar, arremessar. [td. : jogar lanças/ pedras.] [tda. : Quando o dente de leite caiu, jogou -o no telhado.]
>   6. Empurrar (algo ou alguém), ou saltar, pular, lançar-se. [ti. + a : Jogara o carrinho ladeira abaixo: Foi suicídio, ninguém o jogara da cobertura: Jogou -se no mar.]
>   7. Manejar com destreza ou conforme as regras. [td. : Jogava a espada como um autêntico esgrimista: jogar as armas/ o florete.]
>   8. Balançar, como aceno ou coreografia. [td. : Jogava os braços para o alto, pedindo socorro: A passista seguia o batuque jogando as cadeiras.]
>   9. Balançar-se, agitar-se, oscilar. [int. : O barco jogou muito na viagem de volta: "Negros fantasmas, indistintos, sem forma ondulam, jogam..." ( Brás de Oliveira , Narrativas navais) ]
>   10. Ter como escolha; optar por; investir. [tr. + em : Para atingir um novo público, a empresa jogou nas tendências europeias.]
>   11. Dar destaque a; servir-se de. [tr. + com : Esse quarteto de percussionistas joga muito com o ritmo.]
>   12. Utilizar ou combinar (ger. com propósito artístico). [tr. + com : Era um pintor que jogava bem com as cores vivas e as sombras]
>   13. Estar em harmonia; combinar-se; condizer. [tr. + com : A cor das paredes não jogava bem com a mobília.]
>   14. Funcionar, mover-se. [int. : As molas jogam bem.]
>   [F.: Do lat. joco, as, avi, atum, are. Hom./Par.: jogue (s) (fl.), jogue (s) (a2g.s2g.[pl.]); jogo (fl.), jogo (sm.); joga (s) (fl.), joga (s) (sf.[pl.]); jogar, jugar (em várias fl.).]

Observamos nessas definições que o verbo **jogar** aparece mais nos sentido de jogo (game), jogos de azar, esportes ou de arremessar (lançar algo a algum lugar). Pode ser empregado também no sentido enganação. Exemplo: ela está jogando com você. Ou seja, ela está lhe enganando.

No texto que você propõe não é correto substituir **jogar** por **brincar**.

Answer (score 4):

Uma característica que não vi mencionada acima, e me parece fundamental, é que jogos sempre têm regras bastante explícitas, específicas e bem definidas. As regras das brincadeiras são implícitas, genéricas e bem mais elásticas.

Answer (score 2):

jogar **always** implies that there is a game being played or that is played or whatever..

**brincar is play in all other contexts**, where there is no game, formal or not between two players or adversaries.

That the long and short of it. It's just that simple.